# Clickable chart area to modify another chart's shown values inside the same report

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a report with, two different charts or tables, and i'm required to make the areas or values clickable so when you do, another chart or table shows the details of the clicked value.

The thing is, i don't even know if it's possible to pass values from one chart to another interactively, because i don't think this software was focused on interactive reports.

I know about Hyperlinks with Field Values, and i was thinking about something similar, but passed inside the report, not to a browser.

Comment: Are you looking for a software recommendation?

Comment: @Merrily No, we have to stick with Jaspersoft, i just need to know if it's possible to do it

Comment: Yes, what you want to do is possible. It is not clear to me whether the charts and tables with the detail information need to be in the same report or into a separate report. In any case, you would still need to rely on hyperlinks to send back parameter information to your Web app that would run the report again or run a separate report. In essence, you need a Web application that delivers reports in HTML format and is able to respond to clicks and callbacks that trigger report refresh or trigger the display of a new report. You might want to take a look at JasperReports Server.